# Javascript combine and sort arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Beginner
I have 3 arrays, i would like to combine and sort, according to date and time.
All 3 arrays, only have date and time values.

Example:

```
var slackStart = []; //time the current starts for the week.
var CurrentTurn = []; //time the current turns for the week.
var slackStop = []; //time the current stops for the week.
```

Output slackStart (contains all starting times for the week):

```
[ "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z", "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z", "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z", "2017-10-24T21:40:27Z", "2017-10-25T03:47:20Z"]
```

I need to combine the 3 arrays and sort according to date and time. I also need to know from which array the value came. If its slackStart, i know its the starting time for the current.

I want to display it like this.
Current start: 11/11/17 12:00 
Current turn: 11/11/17 14:00 
Current Stop: 11/11/17 17:00

Combining the arrays is easy but how can i know from which array it came?
I tried using keys but struggled a bit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: change the strings to an object so you can know where it came from. Also, use moment.isBefore in combination with javascript sort() to order them

Comment: I have set it to object. var obj = _.extend({}, slackStart); But how do you change the key from 0,1,2 ect to currentStart for all slackStart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine arrays simply by calling the 'concat' method:

```
     var aryA = [1,2,3]
        ,aryB = [4,5,6]
        ,aryResult = aryA.concat(aryB);
```

'aryResult' will contain [1,2,3,4,5,6], in terms of identifying where it came from, are the dates going to be unique?

If not then you should forget an array and convert to an object with unique key for each entry, then you can simply use the key.

```
    var objResult = {};
    for( var idx in aryResult ) {
        objResult["k" + idx] = aryResult[idx];
    }
```

The above will translate the combined array into an object with each member having a key that starts with k followed by the array index.